# Apache is not starting after configuring subversion (SVN)

Tags: php, apache, svn, xampp

I configured subversion 1.6.6 with Apache. ( I am using XAMPP )
I followed the README.TXT and also few articles in web.
Here are my steps

1. Installed subversion 1.6.6 to C:/Subversion
2. Added C:/Subversion/bin to Path
3. copied mod_dav_svn.so, mod_authz_svn.so into Apache/modules
4. Restarted windows
5. Uncomented the two lines in httpd.conf file

   LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
   LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
6. and added the two lines

   LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
   LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
7. and then added

   <Location /svn>
       DAV svn
       SVNPath C:/repo/svn
   </Location>

at the end of the file

Now I am trying to start Apache in XAMPP, but it is not getting started.
giving the following messages

```
22:13:29  [apache]  Status change detected: running  
22:13:30  [apache]  Status change detected: stopped
```

Comment: svn 1.7 is much fancier.  If you're just starting out with this svn server, you should go with that.  also, when your run `apache_start.bat` from a command prompt - are there additional errors?  You'd likely get better responses over at server http://serverfault.com

Comment: What messages do you get ein your Apache error log, or Event Viewer?

Comment: cannot load c:/xampp/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: The same kind of error for mod_authz_svn.so
I don't understand the reason for this error. I placed the mod_dav_svn.so and mod_authz_svn.so in the modules directory of the apache